# shadowBox: volume but no video

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

I am using the shadow box from http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

My issue is I am showing videos hosted on my server using the shadow box.  Have a hyperlink that calls the page that shows the movie.  If the movie is not cached it plays volume first... for a while.  Then towards the end the video picture will be display.

code is as follows

```
 <a class="starOff" href="../movie.php?movie=MHxHZXR0aW5nIFN0YXJ0ZWQgVmlkZW98NjA4fDQxN3wxNnw2NTB8NjUw" rel="shadowbox;width=650;height=650" title="fun movie" alt="fun movie" >fun movie</a>
```

Then the video is embedded like this

```
 <EMBED SRC="../movie/fun-movie.mp4" WIDTH = "<?= $movieWidth; ?>" HEIGHT = "<?= $movieHeight+$movieMenuBar; ?>" scale="ASPECT" AUTOPLAY = "true" CONTROLLER = "true" LOOP = "false" PLUGINSPAGE = "http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" ></EMBED>
```

Any ideas why it takes forever to show the video, but volume in instantly played?  Also when I just go to the page outside of the shadow box, movie plays perfectly

Comment: I ended up using the <video> tag and adding a .oga file for mozilla and it worked fine.  Never found out why <embed> tag was giving me grief... problem solved with HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one myself by using the `<video>` HTML5 tag instead of `<embed>`.  Had to convert the .mp4 to .ogg for mozilla and it worked fine